# 'one's chest has straitened, yet he doth not utter'

Tags: idioms, translation, popular-refrains

This is a rough translation of a line in Arabic poetry and I can't seem to find a good equivalent to it.

'Ones chest/bosom has straitened/has narrowed so much/distressed/heavied (no more room in his chest (seat of his feelings), there's no appeal for anything in the world anymore, this person has been crushed and has been subject to extreme hardship and rigor. He's had enough and has worn to a frazzle. Life has thrown a lot at him and burdened him with far more than he can bear.) Yet his tongue doth not utter. (Maybe out of self-esteem, he doesnt want to share in other people with his worries). Imagine your chest is so constricted, when you're distressed you try to breathe deep and what have you. He is so full of anguish but still keeps his tongue tied and confines his misery inside and keeps to himself. Has become a captive of himself.

'Ones bosom has straitened' is also used in prayer as in
'O Lord my bosom has straitened and I have sated, so do widen my endurance and lighten my worries, you are most merciful'.

I need a good way of translating this. Is there a good English saying in poetry or prose or anything? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You probably want to avoid "straitened" because most people are unaware of the meaning of "strait" and will understand it to mean "straightened."

Comment: In English, the chest is not the seat of feelings, but of breath.   (The heart is the metaphoric seat of feelings.)  So this is probably not directly translatable.  A straitened chest is a tightened or narrowed chest, one pressed with no room for breath.  In that circumstance, it would be hard to speak, so the *yet* is inapt.

Comment: @phoog: I disagree.  Most people literate enough to read (translated!) poetry would know the meaning.  I'll grant that this is a (probably pitifully small) subset of all English speakers, but one should tailor one's vocabulary to the expected audience, not the least common denominator.

Comment: @jamesqf that's a fair point, but I consider myself to be fairly literate and I misread it as "straightened" several times before I realized what was going on.  It is, anyway, something to be aware of.

Comment: @deadrat I think one's bosom is considered to be their seat of feelings. Isn't there anything said, doesn't have to be exactly the same I'm just trying to gather lots of ideas. Thanks

Comment: @KhalidItb You're right.  That's a somewhat archaic and poetic usage and wouldn't be interchangeable with *chest*.  *Bosom* is also a somewhat old-fashioned word for a woman's breasts.  It also survives in the set phrase *bosom buddy*.  Probably not a good choice.  The gut survives as a seat of feelings.  We even say "gut feeling" for a powerful intuition.  *A blow to the gut* or *gut wrenching* could describe an emotional wound, and both would be compatible with not being able to speak.

Comment: @deadrat I think the expression "getting something off one's chest" somewhat designs the chest as being the seat of feelings, oppressing ones to be more specific...

Comment: This might be a candidate for asking at [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/). I would consider framing the English version of the first line as something like "His heart has been so much constrained" and then pick up with the line "His will is worn down to a nub [or whatever]," if that comes next. It's actually rather difficult to tell which parts of the paragraph beginning with the single quotation mark are lines from the poem proper and which are explanatory notes.

Comment: @Mina I take your point, but I'm afraid I have to disagree.  Certainly what you get off your chest is something that's bothering you, which in itself means that it has engendered feelings.  However, the metaphor is of something oppressive on top your chest, not something within it.

Comment: @deadrat Well, I agree that the Heart *is* the indisputable seat of feelings and my point here is not to challenge that, but I wanted to defend his use of the word chest that can, like in the metaphor, convey the meaning of a virtual place in our anatomy that needs venting, even if it is because of something on top -not within- as you mentioned. After all straitening and narrowing can be results of something on top - not within. And the word seat itself holds the same nuances in meaning -I digress.

Comment: @deadrat However, I am not a native English speaker but a native Arabic speaker (not classical though) so I may be biased in the sense that the work chest is used in Arabic to talk about feelings be they positive or negative.

Comment: @Mina Ah, then you speak at least one more language than I do.  Different languages make different anatomical assumptions.  For instance in English we speak of an octopus' arms, but I'm told that in Japanese those are legs.  You make a good point about the place that needs venting (although I'd call it metaphorical rather than virtual).  But the English association of *chest* with breath makes the word *yet* seem odd.  An native English speaker will expect *so*, which entirely undercuts the point. The concision and beauty of Arabic poetry will be hard to capture wth direct translation.

Comment: As you can tell from the previous comments the idea of a narrowed chest is not an idiom in English. It really depends on if you expect the reader to understand the meaning of the phrase either from prior experience or from context. For example, there are several instances in the English bible which refer to "beating one's breast," which was a gesture of sorrow in the ancient world but not in the modem English speaking world. It is left this way in English translations and if it's not clear from the context the translator might add an explanatory footnote.

Comment: I love the word "straitened" there, btw, although I did think it a typo of "straightened" until I read the body of your question. The thing is, if I am reading poetry I will expect to see uncommon words because sometimes there is just the perfect word due to meaning, metaphor or meter. So personally I like it that way. Poetry is supposed to be as much about the beauty of the words as the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @deadrat I can see how *yet* can seem odd if the OP maintains his *straitened chest* (but part of me is still for maintaining it and dropping the *yet* - Am I not a stubborn non native English speaker...). I would really appreciate a good answer for this question though or at least what the OP has finally come to adopt. As for the octopus, Arabic agrees with English here, so does French, and I am now officially curious to know who stands by the side our friends the Japanese...

Comment: @Mina Here I think stubbornness commends you.  If I don't speak Arabic, I won't be able to fully appreciate Arabic poetry.  But if bilingual speakers don't insist on properly capturing the sense in translation, I won't be able to appreciate the poetry at all.  Why not collect your reasoning into an answer?  Perhaps it will be one that the OP will accept.

Comment: @deadrat I just read your comment (life) and after all those months I am still curious to know what the OP has opted for...

Comment: @Mina *comment (life)*? Do you mean this thread? In any case, thank you for reminding me of our interesting and rewarding conversation from last March. The OP hasn't accepted either of the two answers and has made no further comment here, so I don't know what he has opted for. The OP is still around, so I will ask.

Comment: @KhalidItb Mina and I would like to know what phrasing, if any, you settled on.

Answer (score 1):

The closest English idiom I can think of is to be of heavy heart.  It seems like the mood is melancholy and the behavior to be conveyed is stoicism.  So something like:

One's heart heavy with a lifetime's woes, yet ne'er a word doth he utter

Answer (score 0):

In William Shakespeare’s ‘Romeo and Juliet’, Romeo’s observation that “[**she** {Juliet} **speaks, yet she says nothing**](http://genius.com/4294711) is similar **in structure** to the lovely line you quote, but it has no image of “chest tightening” and its true meaning is subject to debate.
For example, in the annotation (granted, un-reviewed) next to Romeo’s line at the above link, a paraphrased version of the idiom “[His/her/your] [**silence speaks volumes**](http://www.gordontraining.com/free-workplace-articles/silence-speaks-volumes/)” is given as a **possible** explanation of what Romeo meant.

Although, again, no image of “chest tightening” is present in that idiom, it does, however, directly address the notion of the possible significance of/reason for  someone’s silence and depending on the context ...

> [i]t can express lots of different emotions [perhaps even those caused
>   by physical exhaustion] ranging from joy, happiness, **grief**,
>   embarrassment to **anger**, denial, **fear**, withdrawal of acceptance or
>   love ...

... which could perhaps make it relevant to your context.

(Romeo’s line with annotation from ‘Genius[dot]com’ and the quoted interpretation [with emphasis added] of “Silence speaks volumes” from ‘Gordon Training International’)